# How to avoid division by zero error in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to build a dice loss for my model (needs segmentation with masks, so I am using IoU metric).

When it comes to the last part, the division between the intersection and union, I can't overcome the 'float division by zero' part. I have tried using a smooth constant (1e-6), the `if else` and the `try except` clause for the `ZeroDivisionError`.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np


def arith_or(array1, array2):
    res = []
    for a, b in zip(array1, array2):
        if a == 1.0 or b == 1.0:
            res.append(1.0)
        else:
            res.append(0.0)

    return res


def arith_and(array1, array2):
    res = []
    for a, b in zip(array1, array2):
        if a == 1.0 and b == 1.0:
            res.append(1.0)
        else:
            res.append(0.0)

    return res


def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = np.ravel(y_true)
    y_pred_f = np.ravel(y_pred)
    intersection = arith_and(y_true_f, y_pred_f).sum((1, 2))
    union = arith_or(y_true_f, y_pred_f).sum((1, 2))
    score = ((2.0 * intersection + 1e-6) / (union + 1e-6))

    return 1 - score
```

The error:

```
    ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-886068d106e5> in <module>()
     65 output_layer = build_model(input_layer, 16)
     66 model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
---> 67 model.compile(loss=dice_loss, optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

2 frames
/content/losers.py in dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
     30     intersection = arith_and(y_true_f, y_pred_f).sum((1, 2))
     31     union = arith_or(y_true_f, y_pred_f).sum((1, 2))
---> 32     score = ((2.0 * intersection + 1e-6) / (union + 1e-6))
     33 
     34     return 1 - score

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Can you post minimal, reproductible example? In your code `arith_or` returns python's array, which doesn't have a `sum` method - this is a different code and your example is useless.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I thought I was using a numpy array, my bad. Anyway, Peter gave me an alternative solution which works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert, but the dice loss function which I use comes from 'Image Segmentation with tf.keras' by Raymond Yuan (https://ej.uz/hk9s) and it has not failed me once.

The function:

```
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
    y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 1 - dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss
```

It seems, that a float of 1 has just been added both to numerator and denominator.

With numpy it would be:

```
def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = np.ravel(y_true)
    y_pred_f = np.ravel(y_pred)
    intersection = np.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (np.sum(y_true_f) + np.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return 1 - score
```

Comment: Well this doesn't fix my float division by zero error, but the dice loss function works great! Thanks!